# CloudSQL database crashes periodically (Out of memory)

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We are having a problem where our cloudSQL database crashes periodically.

The error we are seeing in the logs is:

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Write to file ./ib_logfile1failed at offset 237496832, 1024 bytes should have been written, only 0 were written. Operating system error number 12. Check that your OS and file system support files of this size. Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
```

From what I understand, error number 12 means 'Cannot allocate memory'. Is there a way we can configure cloudsql to leave a larger buffer of free memory? The alternative would be to upgrade to have more memory, but from what I understand cloudSQL automatically uses all the memory available to it... Is this likely to reduce the problem or would it likely continue in the same way? 
Are there any other things we can do to reduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your system is running out of disk space rather than memory, especially if you are running in a HA config.

(If disk isn't the issue you should file a GCP support ticket rather than here)